# sql query how can I delete rows that have 5 columns identical and leave 1 in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have seen this question being asked before but not in Postgres and not with 5 columns. I am working with Postgres 9.4 and I have a big location table that has some duplicates. There are 5 fields that I want to check for duplicates and those are: **city,state,zipcode,latitudes,longitudes** I have tried other methods such as this [find rows that multiple columns are identical using SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7315852/find-rows-that-multiple-columns-are-identical-using-sql-query) but it kept giving me errors even after I changed the names to match my table and columns. A lot of my rows look like this

1. Chicago IL **60475** 41.881 **-87.6245**
2. Chicago IL 60475 **41.853** -87.6846
3. Chicago IL **60475** 41.881    **-87.6245**
4. Chicago IL 60475 **41.890** -87.6273

There are many with the same city,state,zipcode and slightly different latitudes and longitudes. In the List above only # 1 and # 3 are identical so I would like to delete 1 and leave the other. I am trying to find the correct way of doing this without deleting extra rows any suggestions would be great... 
I got this error on the having query
ERROR:  column reference "city" is ambiguous
LINE 1: Select city,state

```
Select city,state
FROM zipss JOIN 
 (SELECT city,state, count(*)
  FROM zipss
  GROUP BY city,state
  HAVING count(*) >=2) dupl on zipss.city = dupl.city and zipss.state = dupl.state;
```

Comment: So in your sample you keep rows 1 and 2 would be solution?

Comment: What errors did you get with the group by + count method?  and @JuanCarlosOropeza, i believe keeping 2, 3, 4 (or 1, 2, 4) would be the solution since 1 and 3 are the same..

Comment: @MattH Yes, i was just confiming. btw the `group by`is the easy part, i guess OP need the delete part. I'm doing a row_number by partition so delete all but `row =1`.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: exactly my thoughts.  :)

Comment: Yes in the example above keeping rows 1,2 & 4 or 1,3 & 4 would work. The error I got was: ERROR:  column reference "city" is ambiguous
LINE 1: Select city,state . I tried to do it using 2 fields to start of I will update my question and show it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use the `ctid` for this purpose.  This is a built-in column that you really shouldn't use.  But, if you don't have a primary key on a table, then it is useful:

```
delete from table
    where ctid not in (select max(ctid)
                       from table t
                       group by city, state, zipcode, latitude, longitude
                      );
```

This should keep the row with the largest `ctid` for each combination of the five columns.

Comment: Gordon, what a beast.  Always coming in for the win.  Why can't you let noobs like me answer?  You know.. give us little people a shot at answering? ;)

Comment: @MattH . . . I left this question for *20* minutes before answering ;)

Comment: Well.. I never said I was quick!  Also my solution was not nearly as elegant as yours.  +1. :]  Always enjoy learning from your answers.

Comment: I know @MattH,  he is like a ninja. For OP, here is a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9d018/6) so you can see it working. I put an ID column so easy to see what row is being deleted.

Comment: Wow amazing that solved the problem thanks a lot, Postgres is so handy with these tools.